# Разбиение страницы на отдельные файлы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, html5

Как разбить страницу на отдельные файлы? тоесть чтоб хэдер, футер и др хранились в отдельных файлах и при необходимости подключались к странице. Возможно ли это стелать с помощью html? Если нет, то через js, jquery

Comment: лучше использовать сборщик (grunt/gulp) + шаблонизатор (скажем pug). Html тут не поможет, делать это js'ом - некошерно

Comment: Спасибо! Если можно, небольшой пример покажите

Comment: миллион темплейтеров есть. Можно использовать reactjs, но судя по вопросу, реакт еще очень рано изучать) У самого были подобные вопросы. Если используешь богомержкий пхп, то `<? include('../main.html') />`

Comment: Про пхп знаю, но хотел обойтись им

Comment: html - просто язык разметки и всё, там в принципе нету никаких функций, кроме рендера

Comment: можно использовать pug

Comment: Спасибо! буду пробовать!

Comment: ejs - также подойдёт в качестве шаблонизатора.  В нём синтаксис совпадает с html и js

Answer (score 0):

Можно работать с фреймворками. Разбиение одного диалогового окна в браузере на множество блоков.
Создайте отдельный файл со списком действий, а потом в главном  файле сделайте ссылку на этот файл/файлы.

```
<frameset= cols , rows =??? > 
<frame src = " " >
</frameset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если цель собрать простенький сайтик на несколько страниц, и дабы проще было редактировать какие-то общие html-блоки, то можно использовать ещё такую технологию как SSI, не требующет применения каких либо языков программирования, а лишь чтобы она была включена на сервере. Просто в файл, к примеру index.html, подключаете ваши блоки:

```
<!--#include virtual="header.html"-->
<!--#include virtual="content.html"-->
<!--#include virtual="footer.html"-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Накидал небольшой билдер на основе gulp, может пригодится:

https://github.com/MedvedevWeb/gulp-html-builder

В src/pug находится собственно все с чем надо работать, дальше останется лишь разобраться с pug (ну и с gulp на будущее)